# first row in table doesn't respond like the other rows, it can't pass data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, html-table

I am using Laravel 4.2 and Bootstrap for this.. I am trying to update the data in the table, but everytime I do, the first row doesn't respond like the other rows.. here is my .blade.php file. it extends a masterlayout and this is what's inside the section:

```
<form id="Car_Brand" >              
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Car Brands 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAdd">Add</button></div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Car Brand Id</th>
                      <th>Car Brand Name</th>
                      <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    @foreach($carbrands as $cbrands)
                        @if($cbrands->status == 1)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $cbrands->strCarBrandId }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $cbrands->strCarBrandDesc }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button id="btn_edit" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" href="#edit{{ $cbrands->strCarBrandId }}">Edit</button>

                            <!-- Modal Edit -->
                            <div id="edit{{ $cbrands->strCarBrandId }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                              <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <form action="/carbrandUp" method="post">
                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">EDIT</h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Car Brand Id </label>
                                            <input name="car_brand_id_edit" id="car_brand_id_edit" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ $cbrands->strCarBrandId }}" readonly>

                                            <label>Car Brand Name </label>
                                            <input name="car_brand_name_edit" id="car_brand_name_edit" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ $cbrands->strCarBrandDesc }}">
                                        </div>

                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                  </div>
                                  </form>
                                </div>

                              </div>
                            </div><!-- Modal Edit -->           
                    </tr>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                  </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here is my route:

```
Route::get('/CarBrand', "CarController@maintenanceCarbrand");
Route::post('/carbrandUp', array('uses'=>'CarController@updateCarbrand'));
```

and here's what's inside my carcontroller:

```
public function maintenanceCarbrand()
{

    $brands = MCarBrand::all();

    return View::make('carbrandMaintenance')->with('carbrands', $brands);
}

public function updateCarbrand() 
{
    $id = Input::get('car_brand_id_edit');

    $carbrand = MCarBrand::find($id);

    $carbrand->strCarBrandDesc = Input::get('car_brand_name_edit');

    $carbrand->save();
    //dd($id);
    return Redirect::to('/CarBrand');
}
```

I can't seem to find the error here. please help. Thanks a lot.